# Why is it light level 15 at night?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft the light level is at 15 at night, and there isn't any moon out. I'm in a swamp biome (if it makes a difference which biome you are in) and the light level is at 15 (max, as the day).

I've been there in two nights in a row. No monsters are spawning either. I'm playing in a private multiplayer server and monsters is spawning natural (it's not in peaceful). No mods, no plugins, Minecraft Version 1.8.9.

What is happening here? How can I fix this?

Comment: Version? Modded? With plugins?

Comment: No plugins No mod Version = 1.8.9

Comment: Is it your server or someone else?  Can you look at the server configuration?

Comment: Does it look like its as light as daytime, or are you just reading the light level off of F3? Screenshot could be useful.

Comment: Go ahead and answer your own question, so it will help others too in the future. And please don't change the title to "Warning: Stupid Question"

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know how much light it is where you are, don't check in the number in the parenthesis - check the number that is directly after "Light:". It can be hard to see but it's there.

If you read "(15 sky)", that number is always the same if you're outdoors. It will only change if you're indoors.

Comment: even with your answer is is unclear what your actually saying here..

Comment: @Timelord64 I actually happen to know exactly what they're talking about, and can provide a clarifying screenshot in a bit

Answer (score 1):

In the F3 menu, there are 2 values: block light, and sky light. Sky light refers to what the light level is during the day. In the open, this will always be 15. Block light refers to the light level of that block at night, which if there are no light sources around, should be 0.

The fact that no mobs were spawning in that area is likely a coincidence, but could also be related to the fact that mobs will not spawn within a certain radius of the player.

Comment: Nonononono, it's working as intended, this value represents the maximum possible sun light at that block.